# How to get JAX-RS absolute Path from JSF Page?

Tags: jsf, rest, javabeans, jax-rs, cdi

Sorry, I am just starting with all this EJB, JSF and JAX-RS stuff and need your help now.
I have created a JAX-RS Resource class, which works very well and implements @GET, @PUT, etc. Methods.

In the same project I now created a JSF page with the according BackBean. This Backbean should talk to the REST interface. While testing, I hardcoded the URI of the REST Interface into the bean, but of course I would like to get the URI programmaticly. I tried with a @Produces method and injection, but I always get an IllegalStateException. I think this has to do with contexts, but I actually do not have the understandning to solve it.

My REST Resource:

```
@Path("task")
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TaskResource {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

@Inject TaskLifecycle lc;

public TaskResource() {
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Response getTask(@PathParam("id") String id)  { ... etc.
```

My Backbean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@LocalBean
@Named("tmmlWrapper")
public class TmmlTaskWrapperBean implements Serializable {

// Here another ManagedBean is injected, which works fine!
@Inject TaskLifecycle       lc;
```

and finally my JSF Page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Tasklist</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel ><h3>Tasklist:</h3></h:outputLabel>

        <h:dataTable value="#{tmmlWrapper.taskList}" var="tl">

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
            #{tl.id}

        </h:column> ... and so on ... etc.
```

My question:
How can my BackBean get the URI of the REST resource (ex. "http://exampledomain:8080/as")?
Any help is welcome!

Cheers,
Joern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll first need to get access to the underlying servlet container (assumed to one, instead of a portlet container) produced HttpServletRequest object. Use the [`FacesContext`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) object to access the HttpServletRequest object in the following manner:

```
HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
```

The [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) class provides several utility methods to obtain a near representation of the original request:

- [`getRequestURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29), which provides the original request sans the query string
- `getScheme`, `getServerName`, `getServerPort`, `getContextPath`, `getServletPath`, `getPathInfo` and `getQueryString` all of whose outputs can be combined in sequence to obtain the original request. You may have to omit the latter invocations if you want a lesser fragment of the URL.